# How to upgrade weblogic's jaxb implementation

Tags: java, jaxb, weblogic

My weblogic 12c has a jaxb implementation which is causing me some problems, and I'd to investigate further, replacing it, in order to identify if this version of this library is really the problem.

Here is the info inside the Manifest file of glassfish.jaxb_2.0.0.0_2-2-4.jar :

Specification-Version: 2.2.5-SNAPSHOT
Specification-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: jaxb-impl.jar taken from JAXB RI 2.2.4 2.0 Fri O
 ct 21 20:54:48 UTC 2011 
Implementation-Version: 2.2.4
Implementation-Vendor: BEA Systems
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.sun
Extension-Name: com.sun.xml.bind

How can i upgrade this jaxb implementation from 2.2.4 to 2.2.12? Thanks.